# method with some kind of wait statement

Tags: c++, systemc

I need to have some kind of wait statement in SystemC method.
I know that we can't use wait as method doesn't have there own thread like the thread process.
But here my requirement is i have some set of sensitivity list for method and once any of them get trigger the method will get call. And here i want value to get updated based on some event notification till that time i should wit in that method itself, once that even gets notify i have to update the value and comes out of method.

Could someone please help me with this kind of requirement?

I tried using next_trigger(event_name), but somehow it's not working. Here i thought that my method will wait until the event(event_name) gets triggered after that the value gets updated and control will be passed back from method to systemc kernel. But somehow it's not happening.

My sudo code is as below:

```
sc_core::sc_event  event_name;
if(1 == test_signal)
    {
      next_trigger(event_name);
      result = value;
    }
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Now it's working i just modified the code so that dynamic sensitivity will be properly taken care for method.

The modified code is as:

```
sc_core::sc_event  event_name;
if(1 == test_signal)
    {
      next_trigger(event_name);
      if(reg_event_name)
     {
        result = value;
     }
    }
```

Please do let me know if anyone need similar help.